# UK visa refused due to unclear sponsor and lack of ties. What are my options?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm planning on reapplying, please how can I correct these refusal reasons to get my visa approved?

I'm a full time student and I don't know how they want me to own some properties since I entered the university same time I graduated from High School. Also the only way one can prove a legal relationship in my country is by an affidavit.

[image: Refusal Letter]

Comment: They have it in mind that people who do sightseeing and shopping in London have savings and employment and assets and so forth. And shoppers don't require a co-sponsor. You may have to wait until a more prosperous time before succeeding with a visit application.  See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Comment: But every year student from my school visit the UK and end their visit with some shopping. Not any big shopping but just something to remember you of your travel. I'm planning on writing a petition to explain that I'm a dependant and that's why I own no properties. In fact how many students in the UK who are dependant own personal properties.

Comment: To ask them to reconsider their 2nd reason.

Comment: It looks to me as though your 'personal & financial circumstances' are only really coming into play (2nd paragraph in refusal letter) because the visa processing officer was not satisfied that your aunt really is your aunt, that she is your legal guardian and that you are her dependent (1st paragraph in refusal letter). Asking them to reconsider #2 is bound to fail unless you can convince them of #1.

Comment: Great suggestion @brhans. How about getting an affidavit signed by my guardian that she's my legal sponsor?

Comment: @brhans No, that's bad advice. Both problems need fixing seperatley. On the first count, they're not sure that OP is telling the truth about the relationship to the Aunt, or that the Aunt will support the OP. On the second point, they can't see what possible reasons OP would have to *make* them go back to Ghana. Without some obvious pull home, the risk is seen as too high that OP won't go home again.

Comment: But my personal economic status is dependent on my sponsor since I'm a dependant. Also I have showed that I have two more years of study (Accounting). Again if someone's advice is bad what do you propose after all he's not the one in need of the advice.

Comment: @user327302 They don't consider your study enough reason to go back I think. I'm not sure that part is fixable (the first part, about your Aunt, probably is). The fact that your Aunt is your legal guardian doesn't help - the person you are a dependent of is in the UK, so even less reason to return to Ghana...

Comment: Nope. My sponsor is in Ghana now working @Cmaster

Comment: You people are not giving me any advice on what to do. You are just attacking comments

Comment: @CMaster - I'm making the assumption that it is possible for an unmarried student with no significant assets to still qualify for a UK visitor visa if they can show that they have sufficient resources (though a parent/guardian). Of course convincing the official that you intend to return back home is vital...

Comment: @user327302 Ah apologies, I misunderstood that bit.

Answer (score 7):

There are two rejection criteria here. One is easy to resolve, the other less so.

The first point is that they are not sure that your Aunt is related to you as you say they are, or that they are willing to support you. You are going to need to provide some documentation showing that your Aunt is your legal guardian to cover that, and that your Aunt is  willing and (financially) able to support your trip. Whatever this is, you will need to send them.

The second point, and harder to resolve, is that they do not see enough reason for you to return to Ghana at the end of your trip. You have proven that you are still undertaking studies, but that was apparently not enough. They want to see some **need** to return to Ghana. They comment that they cannot see how you are supported day to day - if you could show that your ability to house and feed yourself was dependent on being in Ghana, that may help. Better still would be, as mentioned, property, a business, or a dependent - something you need to go back to look after. I don't see that you could practically acquire these however.

The UK visitor rules are at [Immigration Rules Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

Comment: I know of guys who applied with me and their reason for refusal included none as these as we all had same circumstances. I'm forced to believe that they didn't just wanted to issue the visa in the 1st place. However way it is, I will reapply with an affidavit and also get a reconsideration on 2nd reason. I will let you know whatever happens next but on frank terms, I think I had no suggestions on what to do here.

Comment: @user327302 You want somebody to sit down with you, and sort everything out for you, then pay an Immigration lawyer. If you feel all I have done is explain what, in general, the ECO is looking for, then correct - that's all I can do. Your question is **very** vauge. You want more specific direction? Ask more specific questions.

Comment: Hello guys! Thanks for the help the other time. Everything you people said was true and I would like to commend you on that. However I was able to secure an affidavit to support my relationship to my aunt and that got the 1st reason cleared but I couldn't do anything about the 2nd reason and so the same point 2 was reiterated. I intend to reapply this Christmas, please what do I do???